# How to find the Fourier series of a function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Show that for $\alpha$, not an integer, the Fourier series of

$$\frac{\pi}{\sin(\alpha n)} e^{i(\pi-x)\alpha}$$

on $[0,2\pi]$

is given by   $$\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{inx}}{\alpha +n} $$

My attempt:

I compute $$a_n = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\pi}{\sin(\alpha n)} e^{i(\pi-x)\alpha} e^{-inx} dx$$

$$ = \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{\pi e^{i\alpha \pi}}{\sin(\alpha n)} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-ix\alpha} e^{-inx}dx =\frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{\pi e^{i\alpha \pi}}{\sin(\alpha n)} \left(-\frac{i(1-e^{-2i\pi(\alpha +n)})}{\alpha +n}\right)$$

but I should get as a result $\frac{1}{\alpha +n}$

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The $\sin(\alpha n)$ in your original function seems suspicious - especially since it occurs again as the dummy variable in the summation, and then again in your integral. Is your function really meant to be in two variables?

Comment: I've had a think about it, and if you put $\sin(\alpha \pi)$ instead, everything works out. A couple of hints:

If $n$ is an integer, what do you know about $e^{(i2\pi n)}$?
What's the relationship between $\sin x$, $e^{ix}$ and $e^{-ix}$?